# LOTS of static on my microphone

Tags: microphone

I've been having this issue for a few months now and I've been so frustrated about how much static there is on my mic.

I found a few causes of this static and I do not know how to fix them.

(causes of the static)

My microphone is connected in the rear panel, and front panel audio is disconnected from motherboard. (front panel disconnected because it also caused static)

Need help!

Answer (score 4):

That's not static, it's a bad ground condition.
When hum reduces if you touch a ground plane, it means you're doing a better job than the circuitry at becoming the signal ground.

At best guess, if you have a mic that will plug directly into a PC's mic/headset port, you are starting from the wrong place. You have a high impedance  mic & an almost zero-cost headset preamp in the computer. I think your only chance of even a slight improvement is to make certain the computer is properly earthed.
After that, it's a low-impedance mic & dedicated [external, USB] mic pre-amp.

Comment: I was writing an answer, but it's too similar, lol. With regard to mic, either buy a computer (USB) mic or get a A/D converter outside the PC (e.g. Audio interface).